# Solutions for keyboard with awkward up arrow key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

We have a number of classrooms with this Logitech Keyboard/Mouse device:

> http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400?crid=26

These keyboards are almost perfect, but they have one very annoying flaw: the arrangement of keys around the right shift is such that, when typing, you are very likely to hit the up arrow key instead of the shift key. That moves the cursor completely out of position, so the typist is suddenly inserting characters in the middle of the line above. It's annoying and can be tricky to correct.

Is there a way that I can make it **easy** to re-map an up arrow to act as shift, and switch it back to normal on demand? This needs to be super easy ... I have some instructors who have a hard enough time using normal keyboards, let alone one that asks you to switch modes. Bonus points if you can also have a visual cue for which mode the key is in. All the stations using this keyboard are running 32bit Windows 7 Pro.

[image: 1]

Comment: You're right, that layout *is* irritating. Maybe an AHK-based solution would help.

Comment: Maybe if I setup the macro in advance, and have it switched to work as shift key by default, AHK might work.

Comment: FWIW, we ended up replacing these with K400+ models, which fixes the bad layout.

Answer (score 4):

[MapKeyboard](http://www.inchwest.com/mapkeyboard) might work for you. It seems relatively simple and it is free. I used it to remap <kbd>Right Shift</kbd> to <kbd>Break</kbd> on my keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

[KeyTweak](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/KeyTweak.shtml) does a pretty good job of remapping keys and it is fairly simple.

Ill let you decide if its simple enough for your needs but this is the best solution I know of

Comment: Not quite what the Asker asked for (easy to use by lay-people, with the ability to toggle mappings), but it may be useful for others who come along with less specific requirements.

Comment: @neersighted thats what im hoping. I realize this might not be exactly what he is looking for but I figured Id share it and if he cant use it so be it and hopefully someone else can

Answer (score 0):

Anyone in Linux can use these commands:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 62 = Up"        # => Up
xmodmap -e "keycode 111 = Shift_R"  # => Shift
xmodmap -e "add shift = Shift_R"    # Make the new Shift key actually shift
xmodmap -e "remove shift = Up"      # Prevent the old Shift key from shifting
xset r 62                           # repeat Up key
xset -r 111                         # don't repeat new Shift key
```